# how to insert the data as string and data base should accept as a number

Tags: mysql

I have table named as 'lecturer' and the fields are

```
Id    Name 
-----------
 1     abcd
 2     efgh      
 3     ijkl
-----------
```

where the 'Id' is primary key

I have onother table named as student and fields are

- stdId
- name
- dateOfBirth
- dateOfJoining
- lecturerId

where `lecturerId` is foreign key

Now I want to insert the data in fields as

```
5101
----------
xyz
----------  
10/12/1995
----------
12/10/2011
---------- 
abcd
----------
```

But the data of last column should enter in table "student" as '1' where I'm giving as 'abcd'

My DAOImpl code is

please help me for writing a query .as beginner I'm unable to understand how to write query.. I'm waiting for your responses ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have too much to learn. Start with a decent book or tutorial, then get back to us.

Comment: @janisz    I'm unable to paste my code here I don't know y .can I have  your email Id please ...I'll send my code to you .... and I'm not using any hibernate ..I'm using servlet and my application structure is Controller,Dao,DaoImpl,Model,DBUtill ...

Comment: What's the problem in pasting code snippet? It requres initial work from you to finde core of your question in code that you have? Inserts to DB doesn't work automagicaly. Do as @dan-klasson suggested: first search for lecturerId to wire it with your update. If lecturer doesn't exists you need to insert it and then query for it's id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert into `lecturer` table first. Then get the id of the last insert of that table and insert that in the second query in the field `lecturerId`.